# Sticky option does not work on PostgreSQL connection with master & slave nodes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

We've just created master&slave nodes and set up the connection in `config/database.php` like this:

```
'pgsql' => [
    'driver' => 'pgsql',
    'read' => [
        'host' => [
            env('DB_HOST_READ_1'),
            env('DB_HOST_READ_2')
        ]
    ],
    'write' => [
        'host' => env('DB_HOST_WRITE')
    ],
    'sticky' => true,
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'schema' => 'public',
    'sslmode' => env('DB_SSLMODE', 'prefer'),
    'options' => array(
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
    ),
    'binary_parameters' => 'yes',
],
```

note the `read` & `write` keys. Right below them there is `sticky => true` which should prevent the problem with delay of replication. But it doesn't work the way it should. I can clearly see that because after a form POST request that is inserting data and right after that redirect to a route with the freshly added data it says 404 not found. And after a page refresh the data arrives. What can I do about this? Can I somehow set an option to wait for the replication to happen and after that proceed?

How can I actually test if the sticky option works?

Comment: *The sticky option is an optional value that can be used to allow the immediate reading of records that have been written to the database during the current request cycle* ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database#the-sticky-option)). A redirect starts a new request cycle.

Comment: Okay, how can I prevent this replication delay?

Comment: You can't prevent replication delay but you can serve the newly inserted data in the same request without a redirect

Comment: I must redirect the user to the page where the information is visualized. It's not a one-time page. I mean this page can be accessed by everyone after the insert request. The project is for reviewing other websites. The insert request I'm talking about is adding a new website to the database and then redirect to the page which read from the database and display the website information and reviews. Hopefully you understand me.

Comment: Yes I know it's not ideal but unfortunately there's always some delay between when the time the write database is modified and the changes propagate to the read replicas. You can try setting `sticky` to `false` and do a busy wait for the newly inserted row via one of the read connections before you redirect, but I don't know if this will be foolproof since you have 2 read replicas so one might have the changes before the other.

Comment: The second read replica is just for test purposes. We will have 1 master and 1 slave only.